# How to shrink or magnify the map view in taxi example in RinSim？

Tags: java, rinsim

As I see, the map of Leuven in the taxi example is fixed size. How can I shrink or magnify the map like in Google Maps via mouse wheel or some button on RinSim?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the menu: `View` -> `Zoom in` and `View` -> `Zoom out`. Alternatively you could use a shortcut, e.g. `CMD +` on MacOS.